# How do I fix a "404 page not found" error on the refresh of the React app on production?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have search params in my url ?category=ALL like this the full route is: http://localhost:3030/news?category=ALL

Rerfresh works locally, but not in production. How to solve this issue

Comment: You have to configure your production server to redirect every path to the `index.html`

Comment: I agree with Konrad's comment. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) for more information and try to find a section relevant to the server environment you are deploying your app to.